# Azure Data Factory - Load REST API with nested Array data into Cosmos DB using ADF Copy Activity

Tags: azure-data-factory

We have below REST API Response with objects and nested arrays (Contact , Name).
want to store in cosmos DB as is. When we use implicit mapping in copy activity it is working but want to remove the page information and add upsert logic hence going for explicit mapping.

The data in the cosmos returning only first objects in array and also the array symbol [] is missing.

**REST API Response:**

```
{
"page": 1,
"per_page": 2,
"total": 4,
"total_pages": 2,
"Prospect": [
{
"Contact": [
{
"ContactID": 1,
"ContactType": "aliqua laboris culpa laboris occaecat ullamco Lorem non laborum eu aliqua",
"EffectiveDate": "2022-01-10T13:20:35.335Z",
"IsPrimary": false,
"isPrivate": true
}
],
"PartyID": 23,
"ID": "dolo",
"LastUpdatedDateTime": {
"DateTime": "2021-09-06T12:33:53.891Z"
},
"Name": [
{
"FirstName": "incididun",
"LastName": "cillum do",
"LongName": "cil",
"MiddleName": "veli",
"NameSuffix": "inc",
"NameType": "incididunt commodo adipisicing pariatur",
"Title": "amet occaecat aute",
"isPreferred": true
}
],
"PersonalDetails": {
"CountryOfBirth": "cupidatat",
"DateOfBirth": "2019-03-31T23:23:44.904Z",
"Disabilities": {
"DisabilityDescription": "ea",
"DisabilityType": "fugiat laboris laboris do do est",
"Region": "labore nulla proident ex",
"StartDate": "2021-06-16T08:19:55.818Z"
},
"Disabled": true,
"Ethnicity": "nulla ul",
"Gender": "exer"
}
}
```

**Mapping in copy activity.**
[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/3rDwB.png)

**Cosmos DB**

[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/m5pFH.png)